# Cleaning a dataframe in pandas without messing up alignments

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe of just two columns; the name of NBA teams and their respective abbreviations. I scraped this table from Wikipedia and some of the abbreviated parts contains extra letters (other than the a 3 letter abbreviation). I tried to clean off/remove the extra letters without compromising the arrangements between the Teams and their respective abbreviations. But it seems kind of hard to accomplish.

this is how the table looks:

| `Team Name` | `short` |
| --- | --- |
| `Atlanta Hawks` | `ATL` |
| `Boston Celtics` | `BOS` |
| `Brooklyn Nets` | `BKN` |
| `Golden State Warriors` | `GSW GS[a]` |
| `Utah Jazz` | `UTA UTAH[a]` |
| `New Orleans Pelicans` | `NOP NO[a]` |
| `San Antonio Spurs` | `SAS SA[a]` |

I created a function `def` to go through each row in the abbreviations columns to clean up the ones with longer (>3) letters:

```
def fir_thr(abbrev):    
    for l in abbrev["short"]:         
        if len(l) > 3:             
            l = l[:3]         
    else:             
        return l
```

the results: `fir_thr(abbrev)`

`'ATL'`

In another case, I used a for loop:

`[l for l in abbrev["short"] if len(l) > 3]`

i got results like:

`[ 'GSW', 'UTA', 'NOP', SAS']` without the other contents. How do I go about this?

Thank You

Comment: `df['short'].str.slice(stop=3)`